# How to keep a global copy of jar so that all projects can use the code. Android

Tags: android

I have 3 apps which rely on a single lib (jar). Now when I create 3 apk there would be 3 copies of jar.
Is it possible in android to keep the single copy of jar on device and update it once and all apps get the latest lib.

Comment: see https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/android-developers/c5CxaFSsDfo

Comment: It used to be once upon a time, but not now as every single project needs to have the jar in its libs folder. Crazy but unfortunately true

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse, an easy way to do this is to create a new project, and move the jar into the libs folder of the new project. Then go to project properties -> android and tick "Is Library". Now you can remove the jar from the other projects and add the new library project as a library dependency to all 3 projects and you will only have one place to maintain the jar.

A better approach would be to read up on some dependency management tools like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html) which will allow to add too and run a local dependency management server and that you can use to compile dependencies into your projects. This will let you use different versions of the same jar for different projects among many other powerful features.